# Passing value between classes

Tags: c++, class, share

I'm tryng to pass value between two classes:

```
#ifndef classa_inc
#define classa_inc

#include "classb.hpp"

class classa {
    private:
        int a;
        classb tmp;
    public:
        classa(int);
        classa ();
        int get_a() const;
        int get_b() const;
};

#endif

// ..

#include "classa.hpp"

classa::classa (int _a) : a(_a), tmp(30) {}
classa::classa () : a(20), tmp(30) {}

int classa::get_a () const {
    return a;
}

int classa::get_b () const {
    return tmp->get_b ();
}

// ..

#ifndef classb_inc
#define classb_inc

#include "classa.hpp"

class classa;

class classb {
    private:
        classa *ca;
        int b;
    public:
        classb (int);
        classb (classa *);
        int get_b () const;
};

#endif

// ..

#include "classb.hpp"

classb::classb (int _b) : b(_b) {}

classb::classb (classa *ca) {
    b = ca->get_a ();
}

int classb::get_b () const {
    return b;
}

// ...
#include <iostream>
#include "classa.hpp"
#include "classb.hpp"

int main () {
    classa a(10);
    classa a1; // 20
    classb b(&a1); // pass 20
    std::cout << a.get_a() << std::endl; // 10
    std::cout << a.get_b() << std::endl; // 30
    std::cout << b.get_b() << std::endl; // 20
    return 0;
}
```

I've reading some blogs and tutorials about the topic and I'd like to ask you guys if this the propper way of doing it or there are another way or workaround about doing it, because I got error:

classa.hpp:9:3: error: ‘classb’ no nombra a un tipo

Something like classb don't name a type...any ideas?

Comment: Try without including classa.hpp in classb.hpp

Comment: In this particular case it might help to just include the classa.hpp in classb.cpp and classb.hpp in classa.cpp.

Comment: ***Something like classb don't name a type...any ideas?*** I would search for circular include to understand the reason for the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classb.hpp, the forward declaration of classa is sufficient (class classa;). You do not need to include classa.hpp. Including it will cause a circular dependency: classb.hpp includes classa.hpp, which also includes classb.hpp etc.

So:

```
#ifndef classb_inc
#define classb_inc

//#include "classa.hpp" -> not ok and useless

class classa; // => ok
```

classa.hpp needs to be included in classb.cpp, though, because it needs to know about its implementation.

```
#include "classb.hpp"
#include "classa.hpp" 

classb::classb (int _b) : b(_b) {}

classb::classb (classa *ca) {
    b = ca->get_a (); //needs to know if classa indeed has a get_a() method
}

int classb::get_b () const {
    return b;
}
```

Those changes made the code compile successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Your `classb.cpp`:

```
#include "classb.hpp"

...
```

The compiler expands the `#include` macro, and inserts `classb.hpp`:

```
#ifndef classb_inc
#define classb_inc

#include "classa.hpp"
...
class classb {
...
};
#endif

...
```

It expands the new `#include` macro, and inserts `classa.hpp`:

```
#ifndef classb_inc
#define classb_inc

#ifndef classa_inc
#define classa_inc

#include "classb.hpp"

...
classb tmp;
...
#endif

class classb {
...
};
...
#endif

...
```

The compiler expands *that* `#include` macro, and inserts `classb.hpp` again:

```
#ifndef classb_inc
#define classb_inc  <--

#ifndef classa_inc
#define classa_inc

#ifndef classb_inc  <--
...
#endif

...
classb tmp;  <--
...
#endif

class classb {
...
};
...
#endif

...
```

Notice the two marked lines; the first defines `classb_inc`, so the second omits everything until the `#endif`. This is correct behavior for an include-guard. But now there is no definition of `classb` before the third marked line, and the compiler complains that it doesn't know what a `classb` is.

The solution: `classb.hpp` need not include `classa.hpp`.

```
#ifndef classb_inc
#define classb_inc

//#include "classa.hpp"

class classa;

class classb {
...
};
```